# 'subquery returns more than 1 value' ERROR in Stored procedure creation

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

learning the concept of procedures and thought of trying something on my own.

1)
i have a table having the foll columns
loan_no
r_interest

loan_amt

loan_date

time_yr

2)

i created a procedure

```
create procedure proc_update1

as
begin
 declare @interest as decimal

declare @rate as int

declare @p as int

declare @n as int

set @rate=(select r_interest from bank_details)

set @p=(select loan_amt from bank_details)

set @n=(select time_yr from bank_details)

set @interest =(@p*@n*@rate)/100

alter table loan_details add interest1 decimal

update loan_details set interest1=@interest

end
```

3) when i executed using `exec proc_update1`

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc_update1, Line 9
>
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc_update1,
>   Line 10
>
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc_update1,
>   Line 11
>
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. Msg 2705, Level 16, State 4, Procedure proc_update1,
>   Line 13

have i misunderstood anything ???

Comment: Your variables `@rate`, `@p`, and `@n` can only hold one value at a time.  If you want to want to calculate for each row, as you suggested in your comment on @BClaydon's Answer, then you need a way to join data from the two tables together.  What field is common to both `bank_details` and `loan_details`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I misunderstood the question. You have a table with loan amounts, time, and interest rates. You have a column in some table, either the original or a new table. You can update the rows with the following query.

```
UPDATE loan_details
SET interest1 = 
    (
    SELECT (loan_amt*time_yr*r_interest)/100 AS 'interest'
    FROM bank_details
    )
```

However you should have a primary key so you could add:

```
WHERE loan_details.Account = bank_details.AccountId
```

If you want to add a column in a reusable stored procedure you must first check if the column is already there before proceeding.  You do this by querying sys.columns. If the column doesn't exist then it is added. If the column doesn't exist then nothing happens.  Regardless, you move forward to with your UPDATE loan_details.

```
IF EXISTS
    (
    SELECT * FROM sys.columns
    WHERE Name = N'columnName' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tableName')
    )
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE MyTable
    ADD NewColumn1 INT DEFAULT 1
END
```

Comment: No need for a subquery here: `select @rate = r_interest from bank_details`

Comment: @BClaydon, but if i use top 1, then interest will be computed only for that row.whereas what i want is the interset to be claculated for all the rows.

Comment: @mr.Reband Ah, neat.  Don't you still new to force it to return only one row for the upcoming interest rate, or will the interest rate be calculated for each row?

Comment: The scalar variable will only hold the first row returned.

Comment: @mr.Reband, sorry messed up with the table names... i copied the data into a new table.ban_details2.i changed the table names to bank_details2.Now am getting the foll error:Invalid column name interest1

Comment: @SVS do you want to update each row in bank_details with that rows interest rate?  If so, add the interest rate column to that table, then try this; UPDATE bank_details
SET interest1 = 
 (
 SELECT (loan_amt*time_yr*time_yr)/100 AS 'interest'
 FROM bank_details
 )

Comment: @SVS, sorry I misunderstood the question. I change my answer based on what I understand your question to be.

Comment: @BClaydon  i ill try and let you know.but now i debugged a few places and my query is running fine,but giving totally a wrong answer(1125) which is not a result fr any of the rows.

Comment: @BClaydon Yes the abouve suggested query is working fine.But i still don't understand why i couldnt add a column in a procedure ?

Comment: Do you want to add a column in a reusable stored procedure or once from SSMS? If it's in a reusable SP you'll need to check if the column already exists. I'll see if I can add something that checks to see if a column exists, and if it doesn't then add it.